# Ubuntu 15.10 - Can't connect to wi-fi networks using USB wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 15.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 my USB Wifi adapter TP-LINK model (TL-WN722N) behaving strangely, it gets disconnected frequently & when I try to connect to any network I get below message.

> (1) Creating object for path
>   '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4' failed in
>   libnm-glib

Then every time I have to restart the network-manager service to connect to Wifi Network. Is there any solution to fix this permanently